# rails3-jquery-autocomplete not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, jquery-autocomplete

I am following this tutorial [https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete][1], but I'm having problems.

My models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :category_id

  belongs_to :category
end
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "categories", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
  end

  create_table "products", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end
```

Here is my controller:

```
autocomplete :category, :name
```

My layout has this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "autocomplete-rails.js"  %>
```

My routes has this:

```
  resources :products do
    get :autocomplete_category_name, :on => :collection
  end
```

And my form has this:

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :category_name, autocomplete_category_name_products_path %>
```

I have the autocomplete-rails.js in my app/assets/javascript folder. Yet for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method `category_name'
```

Comment: Did you restart the web server after updating your routes?

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :category, autocomplete_category_name_products_path, :id_element => '#product_category_id' %>
<%= f.hidden_field :category_id %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the gem installed and bundled then restart the server again

```
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete`
```